# Android Why switchCompat.setChecked(true) not working after back from BackStack

Tags: android, switchcompat

I excute `switchCompat.setChecked(true)` in the `onViewCreated(...)` of **Fragment**.It works well first time but not working after back from the BackStack.
The log show that `switchCompat.isChecked()` is **true**,but the UI state of **SwitchCompat** is off.It is so strage that the parms named **isChecked** of **onCheckedChanged** in **OnCheckedChangeListener** is also **false**.

Could anyone tell me why ?

**The Fragment**

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ......other code......

    initialSnooze();

}


private void initialSnooze() {
    mSwitchSnooze.setChecked(mAlarm.isSnooze());
    Log.d("TAG", "initialSnooze: "+mAlarm.toString()+" "+mSwitchSnooze.isChecked());
}
```

**Switch to next Fragemnt**

```
 private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment,String tag){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);        
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**Back button to back from BackStack**

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //回退栈中有Fragment
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

**In the Second Frahment **

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mAlarm = getArguments().getParcelable(PARAM_ALARM);
    }
    mAlarm.setSnooze(true);
}
```

Comment: Can we see code which you are trying?

Comment: Post some of your code.

Comment: I posted the code @jaydroider

Comment: I posted the code@pRaNaY

Comment: Try to call `initialSnooze();` in `onResume() { .. } ` method of fragment.

Comment: add second  fragment at top Instead of replace it with your first fragment

Comment: @pRaNaY it works,but I also want to know why? `onViewCreated` will be excute when back form BackStack and the View also were created,why `onResume`

Comment: Thanks for answer @mehdiakbarian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call initialSnooze(); in onResume()

Answer (score 0):

switchCompat will restore state in OnViewCreate. So if you set switchCompat in OnCreateView, it will be cover.